# Idiomatic CSS BEM nesting

Tags: css, bem

I really want to like the ideas behind BEM, but sometimes it's hard for me to decide how to model what I'm doing. For example:

```
<ul class="events">
  <li class="event">

    <!-- We could go this way... -->

    <div class="event__meta event__meta--title"></div>
    <div class="event__meta event__meta--date"></div>
    <div class="event__meta event__meta--location"></div>

    <!-- Or should event__meta be event-meta? -->

    <div class="event-meta event-meta--title"></div>
    <div class="event-meta event-meta--date"></div>
    <div class="event-meta event-meta--location"></div>

    <!-- So now, should event__meta--title be  event-meta__title? -->
    <!-- Or maybe event__title? -->
    <!-- Or should event-meta wrap them all? -->

    <div class="event-meta">
      <div class="event__title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-meta">
      <div class="event__date"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-meta">
      <div class="event__location"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Should event-meta revert to event__meta now? -->
    <!-- Should event__title and friends now be event-meta__title, etc.? -->

  </li>
</ul>
```

What would be the idiomatic BEM way to handle scenarios like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **What to do about grandchild selectors?**

I see that your problem is deciding what to do with grandchild selectors, which is a common reason why some people avoid using **BEM** in the first place. Hopefully this post will make things easier to understand about the front-end development methodology in question.

---

Lets make this clear with the following example:

```
<ul class="events">
  <li class="event">
    <div class="event__meta">
      <div class="event__meta__title"></div>
      <div class="event__meta__date"></div>
      <div class="event__meta__location"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Given this example, you can see that naming can get out of hand and you end up with more and more nested components.

---

**Avoid multiple element level naming.**

You should use the Element level once in your selector name, remember that BEM stands for Block__Element--Modifier not Block__Element__Element--Modifier.

---

**BEM naming is not strictly tied to the DOM**

Independently on how many levels deep a descendant element is nested, it should follow the naming convention with the Block level. BEM is all about making things easier for developers to identify relationships between different components and their top-level component, the Block.

This said, the previous example would look something like this:

```
<ul class="events">
  <li class="event">
    <div class="event__meta">
      <div class="event__title"></div>
      <div class="event__date"></div>
      <div class="event__location"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

A final example:

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/u836whns/)

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.main-content {
  border-top: 20px solid #7B1FA2;
  background-color: #9C27B0;
  padding: 2em 1em;
}
.events {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.event {
  background: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 2em 1em;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}
.event:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
.event--is-first {
  order: -1;
}
.event__meta {
  padding: 2em;
  font-family: 'Copse', serif;
}
.event__title,
.event__date,
.event__location {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}
.event__title {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.event__title--big {
  font-size: 3em;
}
.event__date {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.event__date--underlined {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.event__location {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.event__location--right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <ul class="events">
    <li class="event">
      <div class="event__meta">
        <div class="event__title">
          Festival of life and death traditions
        </div>
        <div class="event__date">
          From October 30th to November 2nd
        </div>
        <div class="event__location">
          Cancún, México
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="event">
      <div class="event__meta">
        <div class="event__title event__title--big">
          Sacred Mayan Journey
        </div>
        <div class="event__date event__date--underlined">
          May 22nd and 23rd
        </div>
        <div class="event__location event__location--right">
          Cancún, México
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="event event--is-first">
      <div class="event__meta">
        <div class="event__title">
          Ran out of names
        </div>
        <div class="event__date">
          August 13, 2016
        </div>
        <div class="event__location">
          Hermosillo, México
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

---

**MORE INFO:**

[Battling BEM (Extended Edition): 10 Common Problems And How To Avoid Them](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/06/battling-bem-extended-edition-common-problems-and-how-to-avoid-them/)

[More Transparent UI Code with Namespaces](http://csswizardry.com/2015/03/more-transparent-ui-code-with-namespaces/)

*Events*

[Xcaret](http://www.xcaret.com/events-xcaret-cancun.php)

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Suppose `title`, `date`, and `location` all shared a common style (like some padding), but have their own styling otherwise (title is bold, etc.). How would you approach this (preferably avoiding child selectors)?

Comment: The thing about BEM is that it is thought in a way that you shouldn't be using child selectors. I covered exactly what you're asking in the final example [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/u836whns/), using comma-separated selectors that will share the same css properties, which cuts down verbose. If you're wondering if you should add another class like shared-properties and use it in every element, the answer is no.

Comment: Sorry, I think my use of "elsewhere" was unclear. If I wanted to show only the next event prominently elsewhere on the page in a "Title • Date • Location" style, the comma-separated approach leads to inflexibility. Now for `event__title`, `event__location`, and `event__date`, I need to be aware of all other contexts that the class was used in and undo them, and it will still be unsafe to future changes. A shared property or committing to more rigorously (or always) use a modifier in cases like this would have avoided this problem.